# Razor: Handling a list of objects within a view, and model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have two classes like this (to make it simple)

```
public class Page
{
    int pageNumber;
    string content;
}

public class Book
{
    public string name;
    public List<Page> pages;
}
```

Now, in a razor view, I have a form allowing to add a book, with a list of pages in the form, to add pages.

Currently, the pages are added dynamically to the form, and I get the values in my controller using Request.Form for building my list of Pages in the controller. The problem is, how can I validate the model with the pages (something like a page must have a content not empty for example) before entering in the action in the controller.

The fields are added with JQuery in the form. I think it not possible to bind a list of Pages directly to the model in the view, especially when the fields are generated with javascript. But maybe I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use model binding in ASP.NET, even if you're adding jquery form elements, see this to create collections that are binding to model:

[ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

I think your form can be done as that in order to run model binding correctly:

```
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="text" name="pages[0].pageNumber"/>
<input type="text" name="pages[0].content" />
<input type="text" name="pages[1].pageNumber"/>
<input type="text" name="pages[1].content"/>
<input type="text" name="pages[3].pageNumber"/>
<input type="text" name="pages[3].content"/>
```

With that use, you can receive the Book object from the view to your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Book myBook)
    {}
```

Then, for validation, I suggest you tu use Data Annotation to your model, use  [Required] tag before the content property of page object, or [MinLenght], see this [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28VS.95%29.aspx) about Data Annotations.

```
[Required]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

Then in your view, use jquery.validate (don't forget to enable it in the view) and in the controller, when you receive your model, you can check the modelstate with

```
public ActionResult Create(YourObject object)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            // code when model is valid
    }
}
```

Comment: Avec plaisir! I recommand you to use data annotation in all your data model. If you don't feel comfortable to put data annotation on your business object directly, you can create a kind of view model, the brother of the business object, brother that host all validation, translations etc. I usually do this and I add some fields as List's to fill select boxes and so.

Comment: The thing I need to do is a control on an amount repartition into several classes, and I need to check that the total amount of the classes is equal to the initial amount. So I will create a custom validator and put the annotation for it on the initial model.

Comment: Yes you can :-) It looks very specific and I didn't see basic validation that do that check...

Answer (score 1):

you can validate the pages in JQuery before the data is send to the server.

or you can user a filter.  a filter is a method that is executed before an action is executed. (you may have seen or used the [Authorize] filter)

you can create a filter that validates the data and if the validation fails the request will be redirected to an error page.

[here is a tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

[here is another tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577776/Filters-and-Attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC)

Answer (score 0):

With MVC you can use DataAnnotations on your model properties.

Using `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

```
public class Book{

    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public List<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page{

    [Required]
    public int PageNumber{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

For a deeper understanding read this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: I know the Required Attribute, but that doesn't help me with make the model binder to automatically bind my dinamic list of fields with my List<Pages>. Sorry.